# I am not able to get previous $_GET['variable'] how do i get it?

Tags: php

Showing the error

> Notice: Undefined index: clothCatId in C:\xampp\htdocs\project-cloth\admin\listProduct.php on line 21
> Product List...
> Product deleted successfully...
> Notice: Undefined variable: getProduct in C:\xampp\htdocs\project-cloth\admin\listProduct.php on line 58
> Serial No.  Category    Type    Cloth Category  Brand   Product Name    Price   Image   Description Action

In my project i am clicking on this link to see list of products and also to delete some products

```
<a  href="listProduct.php?clothCatId=<?php echo $clothresult['clothCatId']?>" class="mwk-sub-item"><?php echo $clothresult['clothCatName'];?> </a>
```

when i click on the below link it directs me to the page
http://localhost/project-cloth/admin/listProduct.php?clothCatId=6

I am fetching that clothCatId=6 to get list of products belong to clothCatId 6 by writing

```
if(isset($_GET['clothCatId']) || $_GET['clothCatId']!=NULL){
        $id=$_GET['clothCatId'];
        $getProduct=$product->getAllProductByCategory($id); 
}
```

and retriving all products has clothCatId=6
my database data

```
**Serial No.    Category    Type    Cloth Category  Brand   Product Name    Price   Image   Description Action**
3   men Men's...    Formal Shirts   Blackberrys Men Slim Fit Self De... 1500.00     The formal shirt is sometimes ...   Edit || Delete
4   men Men's...    Formal Shirts   UNITED DENIM    v...    222.00      dfergreg ...    Edit || Delete
```

now i am willing to delete a row from database by clicking on delete link

```
 <td><a href="editProduct.php?productId=<?php echo $result['productId'];?>">Edit</a>|| <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete ?')" href="?delproduct=<?php echo $result['productId'];?>">Delete</a></td>
```

and fetching product id

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['delproduct'])){
    $id=$_GET['delproduct'];
    $delProduct=$product->delProductById($id);
}
    
if(isset($_GET['clothCatId']) || $_GET['clothCatId']!=NULL){
    $id=$_GET['clothCatId'];
    $getProduct=$product->getAllProductByCategory($id); 
}
    
?>
```

I have `$_GET['delproduct']` and getting products Id whichever i want to delete
and delete this record by the method delProductById($id) defined in Product.php page

```
public function delProductById($id){
    $query="select * from tbl_product where productId='$id'";
    $getData=$this->db->select($query);
    if($getData){
        while($delImage=$getData->fetch_assoc()){
            $dellink=$delImage['image'];
            unlink($dellink);
        }       
    }
    $delquery="delete from tbl_product where productId='$id'";
    $delete_row=$this->db->delete($query); 

    if($delete_row){
        $msg="Product deleted successfully...";
        return $msg;
    }else{
        $msg="Product not deleted...";
        return $msg;
    }
}
```

whenever i am trying to delete the record it is not going to delete and showing me the error

> Notice: Undefined index: clothCatId in C:\xampp\htdocs\project-cloth\admin\listProduct.php on line 21
> Product List...
> Product deleted successfully...
> Notice: Undefined variable: getProduct in C:\xampp\htdocs\project-cloth\admin\listProduct.php on line 58
> Serial No.  Category    Type    Cloth Category  Brand   Product Name    Price   Image   Description Action

```
listProduct.php


<?php
    include 'header.php';
    include 'sidebar.php';
    include '../classes/Product.php';
?>
    


<?php
    

    $product=new Product();
    $fm=new Format();
?>
    
<?php
    
    if(isset($_GET['delproduct'])){
        $id=$_GET['delproduct'];
        $delProduct=$product->delProductById($id);
    }
        
    if(isset($_GET['clothCatId']) || $_GET['clothCatId']!=NULL){
        $id=$_GET['clothCatId'];
        $getProduct=$product->getAllProductByCategory($id); 
    }
        
?>
    
    


<div class="box">
    <h4>Product List...</h4>
    <div class="block">

        <?php
            if(isset($delProduct)){
                echo $delProduct;
            }
        ?>
        <table class="list-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Serial No.</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Cloth Category</th>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>

                
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <?php
                    if($getProduct){
                        $i=1;
                        while($result = $getProduct->fetch_assoc()){
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>  
                    <td><?php echo $result['catName'];?></td>  
                    <td><?php echo $fm->textShorten($result['clothType'],5);?></td>  
                    <td><?php echo $result['clothCatName'];?></td>  
                    <td><?php echo $result['brandName'];?></td>  
                    <td><?php echo $fm->textShorten($result['productName'],20);?></td>  
                    <td><?php echo $result['price'];?></td>  
                    <td><img src="<?php echo $result['image'];?>" height="40px" width="40px";></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fm->textShorten($result['description'],30);?></td>    
                    <td><a href="editProduct.php?productId=<?php echo $result['productId'];?>">Edit</a>
                     || <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete ?')" href="?delproduct=<?php echo $result['productId'];?>">Delete</a></td>  
                </tr>

                <?php } } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
    
<?php
    include 'footer.php';
?>
```

how to solve the ablove error please help me.

after clicking on delete link i am getting url
**http://localhost/project-cloth/admin/listProduct.php?delproduct=38**

and not able to get url
**http://localhost/project-cloth/admin/listProduct.php?clothCatId=6**
again

Comment: First of all you're wide open to SQL injection. And secondly, there's no `clothCatId` named parameter in the url and thus the error. You need to add the `clothCatId` with the `productId` in the url while generating the delete URL.

Comment: Omi Shah thank u but can u please tell me how can i store my first url which has clothCatId and how can i redirect the page to url http://localhost/project-cloth/admin/listProduct.php?clothCatId=6 after deleteing record because when i click on delete now i have url http://localhost/project-cloth/admin/listProduct.php?delproduct=38 not able to get first url

Answer (score 0):

This is causing the warning:

```
if(isset($_GET['clothCatId']) || $_GET['clothCatId']!=NULL)
```

`||` should be `&&`. With `||`, it performs the second test whenever the first test fails, and this warngs because `$_GET['clothCatId']` isn't defined.

You can combine them:

```
if (!empty($_GET['clothCatId']))
```

`empty()` checks whether the variable is set and also if it's empty.

Your link for deleting a product only has `delproduct` parameter. You should also send the category ID to list the category after deleting.

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete ?')" href="?delproduct=<?php echo $result['productId'];?>&clothCatId=<?php echo $result['clothCatId'];?>">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Barmar thanks for reply first i am getting clothCatId and used this tofetch all products fromdatabase then i clicked on delete link and got link     http://localhost/project-cloth/admin/listProduct.php?delproduct=38  now i have delproduct--which is the id of the product i want to delete and i am getting it with $_GET['delproduct']  and i deleted that row whatever i want but now i dont have clothCatId and i am also not getting link   http://localhost/project-cloth/admin/listProduct.php?clothCatId=6  by this link i was fetching all products belong to this clothCatId

Comment: so the problem here is i am not able to get my first url    http://localhost/project-cloth/admin/listProduct.php?clothCatId=6

Comment: @Barmar, sir, isn't this issue is because there's no parameter named `clothCatId` in the url?

Comment: I've updated the answer. You need to incluide the `clothCatId` when you send `delproduct=XX`